# New users not showing in developer console

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I have recently put a paid app online in the google play store.
It was going great but recently the developer console has stopped showing any new users.

I had a piece of code that saved every new user in my database (it saved it when the user first open the app after installation).
And it is not possible that one person is saved twice so i know that every user is unique.

And it showed me the same amount of users as in the developer console until a few weeks ago. I haven't seen any new users in the dev console but i have seen about 10 new users in my database.

My question is is it possible that the dev console is not showing my users correctly? It was showing them correctly and then completely stopped showing new users.

Answer (score 1):

It happens from time to time that statistics are not updated immediately or for one or two days. Last time it happened to me I [contacted support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769) and the fixed it right away.

Comment: I was aware of the issue that the user gets delayed but as example the dev console says that i didn't have any new users sinds 2 October but i have a new user that installed the app on 6 October. Do you think it can be delayed  for a longer period of time like in this case for a week.

Comment: I should not happen but it does from time to time. Contact support